# Very low number of videos returned in search requests

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to find music videos uploaded between specific dates and it seems like the number of videos returned is much below what could be expected.

I called the **youtube/v3/search** endpoint with these parameters

```
key: ***
part: snippet
publishedAfter: 2023-07-01T00:00:00Z
publishedBefore: 2023-07-10T00:00:00Z
type: video
maxResults: 50
order: viewCount
q: music video
```

So, I requested all videos uploaded between 2023-07-01 and 2023-07-10 (10 days range) and related to the words "music video". The response only gives 15 elements :

```
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "UBCEQ_0Y6Jia19Ygs6uKoD9gFws",
"regionCode": "FR",
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 15
},
"items": [
    ... the 15 snippets ...
]
```

The pageInfo element shows **"totalResults": 1000000** and even though the documentation **youtube/v3/docs/search/list** states that this number is an approximation

> pageInfo.totalResults

> The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.

it seems that there are a lot of videos matching the criteria missing. Only 15 elements in 10 days while it's etimated that 3.7 millions videos are uploaded every day. It seems unrealistic.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Since it's an aproximation, it's difficult to say if you're missing something. You could try to search "music videos" on the YouTube website and select the filter (*this month*) - example: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=music+video&sp=EgQIBBAB and see how many videos you will get. You might have a lot of videos and not all of those are from France, so, you have to play with what the API returns. Could you share the snippet results?

Comment: On Youtube, the search with "This month" filter returns hundreds, thousands if not more results, it's an infinite scroll.
I tried the api call with US regionCode but the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the YouTube API, try this:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=music%20video%20after%3A2023-07-01%20before%3A2023-07-10&regionCode=FR&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

[Try it here, in the API Explorer feature.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es-419&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22q%22%3A%22music%20video%20after%3A2023-07-01%20before%3A2023-07-10%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22FR%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D)

Explanation:

I didn't use the `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters and instead, I did use the search operators shown in the source<sup>1</sup> and supplying the search with your search terms you used in your example/question.

I did double check the results (*by searching on the YouTube website*) and the results are *kind of* the same amount = in my test 32 videos were returned by the API and 28 videos were returned by the website.

Results from the YouTube API:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "q3js1SBXLOVYHzjJ1By0wdb-6fg",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 32
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "WOBsQL9n8Fx4ANB-Nt0tkBJa9Ks",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "qJcfMeAeZAQ"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-07-07T04:00:17Z",
        "channelId": "UCX-OWRcv5AZFGoSFxVoiTYA",
        "title": "LANY - Alonica (Official Music Video)",
        "description": "Listen now: https://stem.ffm.to/alonica New merch: https://lanymerch.com Sign up at http://thisislany.com Video Director: Paul Klein ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qJcfMeAeZAQ/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qJcfMeAeZAQ/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qJcfMeAeZAQ/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "LANYVEVO",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2023-07-07T04:00:17Z"
      }
    },
    [31 search results ommited]
}
```

Consider add more keywords and/or amplify the date range to your search request.

Also, consider that YouTube results are an *estimation*, so, maybe there are videos not to be shown for a variety of reasons and we don't know how they operate their software, so, you have to work with what they have *publicly* available.

If you consider/know if there is a video published at that time range and does not appeared in neither the API nor the website, please, include it in your question here and in the ticket you are going to post on Issue Tracker.

> NOTE: If you still consider this is not a solution, then, post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600) and describe there with more details.

---

<sup>1</sup>Source - [A Guide to Advanced YouTube Search Operators](https://granwehr.com/blog/youtube-search-operators)